# Staking via ledger

Tags: staking

I am staking via ledger. Today I tried accessing my staked balance and it's only allowing me to login via ledger live (as opposed to logging in via the ledger devise itself). Now my staked balance is not showing in my staking pool. Please advise.

I tried logging in via the ledger devise. There is no option to login to the ledger devise today.